# Node.js addon: File I/O via Node.js FileSystem module from the C++ side

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, v8

I am working on a linear algebra Node.js addon (written in C++) and I want to be able to save to and read from the disk all objects I exposed.

For example, `v = la.load(fs.open("vector.out", "r-"));` would load a vector object I previously saved with `v.save(fs.open("vector.out", "r+"));`. (I'm making it up --- the point is I want the user to pass a Node.js object for File I/O and use that object to load/save my object.)

My question(s):

1. How do I access Node.js's `FileSystem` objects from the C++ side? (On the Javascript side the user passes a `fs` object to my `load` function and I want to extract file descriptor from that object.)
2. How do Node.js addons typically solve this? Any tips?

Comment: You must signal node.js to perform an operation, not take over the duty it must perform. For this I suggest using websockets for signaling. Dont mix things up

Comment: Hm, I wanted to use its file descriptor to implement serialization; using websocekts seems rather inefficient.